# Java method not executing after scheduled time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, handler

I'd like to execute a method 10 seconds after I launch an Intent:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(GOOGLE_VOICE_SEARCH_PACKAGE_NAME);
      startActivity(launchIntent);

      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          SonrLog.d(TAG, "TIMEOUT, reconnecting!");
          reconnectSONR();
        }
      }, 10000); //10 second timeout
```

The Intent launches, and my code steps over the Handler, but nothing gets printed or gets called.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I tried the above code and it is working fine. And I can see the log `Log.d(TAG, "TIMEOUT, reconnecting!");` printed in the log. Code that i used.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(GOOGLE_VOICE_SEARCH_PACKAGE_NAME);
              startActivity(launchIntent);

              final Handler handler = new Handler();
              handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  Log.d(TAG, "TIMEOUT, reconnecting!");
                }
              }, 10000); //10 second timeout

        }
    });
```

NOTE: GOOGLE_VOICE_SEARCH_PACKAGE_NAME is pointed to some other package as it is just for testing.